# d3 interaction on click event

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a map with d3 circles showing the site locations, as well as a linechart showing the time trend for each of the site. I am trying to make a particular line highlight when a corresponding circle is clicked. [Here](http://codepen.io/kaz-a/pen/OMKjLZ) is the code. I can't seem to connect the siteIDs with the following function:

```
function highlightLine(id) {
        lineGroup.classed("g-highlight", function(d) {
          return d.siteID == id.siteID;
        });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert a `console.log` as shown below, and it should become clearer:

```
function highlightLine(id) {
    lineGroup.classed("g-highlight", function(d) {
      console.log(d);
      return d.siteID == id.siteID;
    });
};
```

Because you're binding to data that you've run through `d3.nest`, the id of `d` that you're interested in is actually `d.key` not `d.siteID`, which does not exist on that level. So the boolean inside `classed` should be

```
return d.key == id.siteID
```

That will cause the appropriate trendline's `<g>` to have a "g-highlight" class, however it still will not visibly color the line. I believe that's because your css rule `.g-highlight { stroke:... }` applies the stroke to the containing `<g>` instead of the `<path>` inside it. You can change that css rule to be `.g-highlight path { ... }` and that will color the path as you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

To bind the click event in d3 you should select the object with that class and bind the click:

```
d3.selectAll(".g-highlight").on("click", function(d) {
    return d.siteID == id.siteID;
 });
```